# Sequelize.js. How to find object in JSON datatype?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am writing `query JSON` data in `sequelize.js` using `postgres` db.

**Postgres table structure**

```
id: integer,
name: string,
data: json
```

**Here is my data structure**

```
{
    id: 3,
    name: "v4th79j"
    data: {
        phone: "123456789",
        email: "example@gmail.com",
        password: "$2a$10$qCttQ8leMPCzJfE",
        company_id: 2
    }
}
```

**I am writing query like this**

```
var filter = {};
// Filter by email for a user
filter.where = { data: { email: "example@gmail.com"} } ;
Entity.findOne(filter)
.then(function (entity) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(entity))
});
```

but it is not working. *How to find object in JSON datatype?*

Comment: Is there some errors?

Comment: It does not show any error, When code reach there, it stops working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL treat *json* datatype as text so querying about one field is not possible. It stores the raw text of the JSON data in the database, complete with white space and retaining all the orders of any keys and any duplicate keys.

I convert data type to *jsonb* which is introduced in [9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) version of PostgreSQL.

With JSONB, it turns the JSON document into a hierarchy of key/value data pairs. All the white space is discarded, only the last value in a set of duplicate keys is used and the order of keys is lost to the structure dictated by the hashes in which they are stored. We can apply index on specific field and can search any specific field using [sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#jsonb) easily.

You can read more about with practical example [here](https://www.compose.io/articles/is-postgresql-your-next-json-database/)

Comment: I am having a similar topic, I need to add to my http response one attribute with result of one specific key of my JSONB column. Do you know if it is possible?